# Correct way to create association between jobs, applications and users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am creating an app that allows users to create and apply for jobs.

The issue I am having is in getting the associations correct between my three models.

Currently I have the following:

```
 class App < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :user
 end 

 class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :apps, :through => :users
 end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :jobs
    has_many :apps, :through => :jobs
 end
```

In my database table for Apps I have two additional columns for user_id and job_id so that the association can be made correctly there.

I am also unsure how I would create a form for say a new application. Currently I have used the following but because I don't have apps as a nested resource of users I am unsure if this is what's causing the issues:

```
 class AppsController < ApplicationController

 def new
   @user = current_user
   @app = @user.apps.build
 end

def create
  @user = current_user
  @app = @user.apps.create(params[:app])
  if @app.save
    redirect_to user_path
  else
    render new_app_path
  end
end
```

and

```
<%= form_for [@app] do |f| %>

<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :cover_letter %>
    <%= f.text_field :cover_letter %>
</div>

<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :cv %>
    <%= f.text_field :cv %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

It would be great if someone could provide an example of how they would setup the associations for this app and how they would ensure that the related forms worked with this setup.

Thanks in advance for your help!

I have also pushed my app to Github in case that helps anyone: [Github Link](https://github.com/supert56/Jobapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there will be relationship many-to-many between users and jobs.And applications can act as join table (as jobs_users).

so models ...

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :user
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :users
     has_many :apps, :through => :apps
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :jobs,:dependent => :destroy
     has_many :apps, :through => :apps
end
```

And for nested form go through this
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast